# Why do I have Blender 3.1 in AppData Roaming when it has not been installed yet?

Tags: add-on

I am preparing to install an update to an existing add-on and the creator recommends that I bypass Blender and use the OS to install the update directly to the **\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender folder**. Okay, however, I see two versions of Blender there: 3.0 and 3.1, both of which have **\scripts\addons** subfolders with all of my add-ons. What's weird is that I have not installed Blender 3.1 yet, so why the 3.1 folder? And why two sets of add-ons taking up space on my HD? Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever launched the beta 3.1 version ?

Comment: @Gorgious, it could be because I installed the beta version of K-Cycles 3.1, but the folder creation dates didn't correspond. Now that I have Blender 3.1 installed all of my add-ons are now pointing to 3.1. Thank you!